# send mail from flask-mail with a sender different from the signed-in user

Tags: python, flask, flask-mail

I got flask-mail to work fine and here is the code I used:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mail import Mail, Message
import time

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('config.cfg')
mail = Mail(app)

@app.route('/mail/')
def index():
   msg = Message('Hello', sender = 'info@MyDomain.com', recipients = ['info@MyDomain.com'], reply_to = 'visitor@HisDomain.com')
   msg.body = 'Hi ' + time.ctime()
   mail.send(msg)
   return "Sent Ok"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I want to reply to the visitor's email, this is why I added `reply_to = 'visitor@HisDomain.com'`, which does work.

But when I reply to the incoming message:

> ---- On Thu, 20 Apr 2017 15:27:54 -0400  wrote ----
>   Hi Thu Apr 20 15:27:52 2017

as you can see, the beginning of the message says that:

> wrote

which seems like I wrote the message, not the visitor.

I'd like the beginning of the reply to be:

```
<visitor@HisDomain.com> wrote
```

I tried to use `visitor@HisDomain.com` as the sender, but it didn't work. Is there a way to achieve this? I couldn't find a solution in the flask-mail documentation, nor anywhere else.

Thank you.